# Exception with custom font on Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make menu with custom font, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is the code:

```
- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        [CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"PC Senior Regular"];
        [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:18];
        CCMenuItemFont *menu1 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Music ON" target:self selector:@selector(musicToggle)];
        CCMenuItemFont *menu2 = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Back" target:self selector:@selector(back)];
        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menu1, menu2, nil];
        [menu setPosition:ccp(size.width / 2 , size.height / 2)];
        [menu alignItemsVertically];
        [self addChild:menu];
    }
```

Here is the code in my info.plist:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>PC Senior Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>senior.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Exception:

```
2012-07-27 05:42:35.369 Busterball[16089:10a03] In options
2012-07-27 05:42:35.371 Busterball[16089:10a03] -[__NSCFConstantString sizeWithZFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0670
2012-07-27 05:42:35.372 Busterball[16089:10a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString sizeWithZFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0670'
```

I have tried using senior.ttf, just senior, etc.
Both fonts are added as targets for the project. I double checked for correct type case.
What is going wrong?

Comment: Where do yo get this "sizeWithZFont" method?

Comment: @Selkie I don't have this method, I think it is cocos2d method.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem of font. Maybe you can set some breakpoint, see where does this exception come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:"Some Text" fontName:@"MyFont.TTF" fontSize:24.0];
CCMenuItem *item = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label target:self selector:@selector(myFunction)];
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:item];
[self addChild:menu];
```

Your info.plist looks right, and this code has worked for me. That said, I do recommend setting breakpoints and trying to find where your error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

An invalid argument exception means that you are trying to use a method that is not recognized. The problem is your sizeWithZFont method. I have tried to search in the cocos2d documentation and that is not a method in there.